# Date1.before(Date2) is not returning the expected result

Tags: java

I am trying to compare dates in order to find the two closest dates to the current date (today's date).

However, I am not getting the expected result using `Date.before()`.

Code here:

```
Date currentDate;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");

public Date getDate(){
    currentDate = new Date();
    //Toast.makeText(Happenings.this, currentDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return currentDate;
}

public String[] compareDate(Date currentDate){
    String[] closestDates = new String[2];
    //Toast.makeText(Happenings.this, sdf.format(currentDate), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("20/01");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("09/08");
        Date date3 = sdf.parse("24/12");
        Date[] availableDates = {date1, date2, date3}; // dd/mm
        //Toast.makeText(Happenings.this, sdf.format(date1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (currentDate.before(date3)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Happenings.this, "Before Festival", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException e){
        Toast.makeText(Happenings.this, "Catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return closestDates;
}
```

What I am getting now is that `currentDate.before(date3)` evaluates to false and `currentDate.after(date3)` evaluates to true. This is different from expectation as `08/11` should be before `24/12`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging or at least printing out your dates?

Comment: No he hasnt, because then he would have seen that the year of date 1-3 is set to 1970. Also this question has been asked in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but if you try date2.before(date3) and it will evaluate to true, then i would be guessing that simply parsing day and month sets the year to default 1970 instead of the current year.
If this is the case then i suggest you either manually set the year, or add the year to sdf.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the year of date3 is set to 1970